# Rails 4, Amazons3 - CORS, froala-editor: Amazon s3 CORS policy appears to allow uploading of images on creation but not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, cors, froala

I am using the Froal-editor in my rails app and uploading images to Amazon S3. I have a strange problem. My site has a questions and answers section and for both questions and answers you can upload images. When a user creates a question or response and uses the editor to upload an image it works great. But that user also has the ability to edit their question or response. If they go back to their question and try to add another image or remove the current image and tehn add another image I get a

```
   POST https://breatheimagevaultdev1.s3.amazonaws.com/ 403 (Forbidden
```

error.

And in firebug it says

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with"
  , "$key", "uploads/"]</Message><RequestId>3DCD6323247DF507</RequestId><HostId>x8HscPCt7rwDX+35AaPxbd
   /H9ycBPjiewTni/CI3KBSnyqqn4rtzZAtlGCYUS5sEQs+shpuUen0=</HostId></Error>
```

This occurs elsewhere in the site - creating something with an image is fine, but going back and making an edit triggers an error.

Here is my CORS config:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
     <MaxAgeSeconds>5000</MaxAgeSeconds>
     <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
```

I am guessing its related to this,

Answer (score 1):

It looks more like you're not creating the policy string correctly. Are you using https://gist.github.com/stefanneculai/deed108fad534d0db3ff?